# Remove ABS P Trap

Tags: plumbing, drain, abs

[Related](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/57529/how-should-i-replace-this-abs-p-trap-and-drain)

[image]

I have an ABS p trap that doesn't seem to have any union nuts. Where my finger is pointing is the tail piece nut that I can loosen (and probably remove), but the rest of the p trap doesn't seem to have any removable parts (its a slow draining sink so I want to remove it, check for clogs, and snake it from lower).

House built in 1958 (idk if this is original plumbing). I don't see how the ABS is connected to the PVC drain and I don't see how to remove it besides cutting it off (and then be stuck with whatever pipe I believe is inside/between the pvc and abs). Is cutting the only way to remove this? Should I get a plumber to fix this?

Comment: Have you removed The expanding foam so we can see if we t can be unscrewed or has to be cut. Be careful you don’t want to cut a galvanized went going to the roof without support or it can possibly move down making repair very difficult

Comment: I have removed the foam, I'll try to add an image later today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cutting is the only way to get it off, I doubt that it was original most homes that age were galvanized & cast iron. The supply looks to be galvanized is the reason I would think it’s not original. They didn’t leave any good place to cut it from what I see. You will probably need to remove the expanding foam hopefully there will be a hub or something you can work with to make the new p trap. It may be possible to unscrew from the main pipe but we won’t know until the foam is removed.

Comment: Yes, remove the foam.